# Re-opening a file in python gives permission error

Tags: python, pygame, speech-recognition, mutagen

I have searched and tried to implement solutions suggested here:
[Errno 13 Permission denied: 'file.mp3' Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818922/errno-13-permission-denied-file-mp3-python?rq=1)
[Error while re-opening sound file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998135/error-while-re-opening-sound-file-in-python)

But there doesn't seem to be any good solutions to this. Here is my code, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Requires PyAudio and PySpeech.
import time, os
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame as pg
import mutagen.mp3

#Find out what input sound device is default (use if you have issues with    microphone)
#import pyaudio
#sdev= pyaudio.pa.get_default_input_device()

def play_music(sound_file, volume=0.8):
    '''
    stream music with mixer.music module in a blocking manner
    this will stream the sound from disk while playing
    '''
    # set up the mixer, this will set it up according to your sound file
    mp3 = mutagen.mp3.MP3(sound_file)
    pg.mixer.init(frequency=mp3.info.sample_rate)
    pg.mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
    try:
        pg.mixer.music.load(sound_file)
        print("HoBo Sound file {} loaded!".format(sound_file))
    except pg.error:
        print("HoBo Sound file {} not found! ({})".format(sound_file,   pg.get_error()))
        return
    pg.mixer.music.play()
    while pg.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        continue
    pg.mixer.quit()
    sound_file.close()

def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    # pick a mp3 file in folder or give full path
    sound_file = "audio.mp3"
    # optional volume 0 to 1.0
    volume = 0.6
    play_music(sound_file, volume)

def audioIn():
    # Record Audio from Microphone
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    # Google Speech Recognition
    try:
        # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
        # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
        # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: ", data)

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return data


def hobo(data):
    if "how are you" in data:
        speak("I am fine")

    if "what time is it" in data:
        speak(time.ctime())

    if "where is" in data:
        data = data.split(" ")
        location = data[2]
        speak("Hold on Sir, I will show you where " + location + " is.")
        os.system("chromium-browser https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + location + "/&amp;")

# Starts the program
#time.sleep(2)
speak("Testing")

while(data != "stop"):
    data = audioIn()
    hobo(data)
else:
    quit
```

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? Stackoverflow isn't a site for just throwing code at people and expecting them to see what's wrong. Where in the code does it crash?

Comment: And the first thing I suspected was that you just weren't properly closing the file so when you tried to reopen it it was already in use. It appears you're calling `.close()` on a string variable (`sound_file.close()`). Are you sure that's what you're supposed to do with Mutagen? I'm not going to take the time to read through the docs for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry, this is the first time I've used stackoverflow. I will do better the next time :)

You actually helped point me in the right directed, adding a mp3.save() to the play_music function helped me progress. 

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the fix in one of the original threads I already went over. The fix was to implement a delete() function like so:

```
def delete():
    time.sleep(2)
    pg.mixer.init()
    pg.mixer.music.load("somefilehere.mp3")
    os.remove("audio.mp3")
```

and changing the play_music() function so it includes the delete() function in the end (and I removed the sound_file.close() statement of course).

Answer (score 0):

Follow below method

```
import time
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame

def Text_to_speech():
    Message = "hey there"
    speech = gTTS(text=Message)
    speech.save('textToSpeech.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("textToSpeech.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(3)
    pygame.mixer.music.unload()
```