# Python pygame "an integer is required"

Tags: python, pygame

I have a function using gTTS, pygame and os modules:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame as pg
from os import remove as OSremove

music = pg.mixer.music

def speak(x):
     sound = gTTS(text=x, lang="pl")
     sound.save("temp.mp3")
     pg.mixer.init()
     music.load("temp.mp3")
     music.play("temp.mp3")
     pg.quit()
     OSremove("temp.mp3")
```

And I'm getting an error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str). [Image here because I have 5 rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyKEt.png)

Comment: Just read the relevant docs. It's telling you `play` doesn't take strings. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the answer above is correct as far as it goes, but let's look a little deeper at it since you're clearly new to this.

First of all, when you get an error message, *read it*. In this case, it's telling you that it wants an integer and you're giving it a string. So, clearly, you misunderstood something.

Next, have a look at the documentation. Google `pygame.mixer.music.play` and it'll pop right up.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play

Next, look at the documentation. In this case it says:[image: this]

`play` takes two arguments, `loops` and `start`, both of them defaulting to 0. No strings -- so you're giving it the wrong argument.

Look further on the Google results and you'll see an SO question: [How play mp3 with pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746263/how-play-mp3-with-pygame)

And that will lead you to some example code in another SO answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, and do you maybe know how to check if mixer is initialized? I can't find the answer, and I don't want to ask question if not necessary

Comment: There's documentation for that too: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_init

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the name of the music file to the `play` function. Just call `play()` without parameters and it should work.

See the documentation of the `play` function:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play