# Pygame music error

Tags: python

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
test = "space.ogg"
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
pygame.mixer.music.load(path.join(snd_dir, 'space.ogg'))
pygame.mixer.music.play(test)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

it comes up with an error when i try to run the code

ERROR:
     pygame.mixer.music.play(test)
    TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: The error complains about a parameter being string instead of integer. Your parameter (feed from test, which is "space.ogg") is string. That seems pretty clear as error messages go. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

`play` takes two arguments, `loops` and `start`, both of them defaulting to 0. No strings -- so you're giving it the wrong argument.

You pass to play method a string (space.ogg) and this is the error

Look further on the Google results and you'll see an SO question: [pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746263/how-play-mp3-with-pygame)