# How to play music in python using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)#any mp3 file
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
  pygame.time.Clock().tick()
```

I know this is the code to play the music in python with pygame
**Can you explain why we use**

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
   pygame.time.Clock().tick()
```

Comment: Basically, *you don't have to call the `Clock.tick()` function (in this case)*; in fact I haven't seen someone create a `pygame.Clock` object on every `tick()` call. To justify any possible uses of the `tick()` method, I believe that more context is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I play an mp3 with pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746263/how-can-i-play-an-mp3-with-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `play()` function is **asynchronous**.It means it won't wait for a return message to continue. And when the program execution reaches the end, mixer object will be destroyed and the music will stop. To avoid that we use

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
   pygame.time.Clock().tick()
```

to run the while loop until the music finishes. Then the mixer object will not be destroyed until the music playing finishes.`get_busy()` method is used to **check if the music stream is playing.**

Answer (score 0):

```
from pygame import*
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('music filename or path with extension .mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: This is not answering the actual question. Please read the whole question, not just the title.