# Pygame mixer not looping

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("music/Recording.mp3")
mixer.music.play(100)
```

is what I'm using right at the start of game code (not in a loop).
i have looked it up and cant find why it wont work

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait while music will ends playing:

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(r'music.mp3')
mixer.music.play(100)
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    continue
```

Comment: This works for me. See for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746263/how-can-i-play-an-mp3-with-pygame