# Pyinstaller pygame.mixer don't play mp3 files?

Tags: python, pygame

**error:**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\\gevent\\greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 259, in _process_message
  File "main.py", line 40, in play_music
pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll: The specified module could not be found.

2020-08-28T18:46:27Z <Greenlet at 0x4b29138: _process_message({'call': 1.305899873486772, 'name': 'play_music', , <geventwebsocket.websocket.WebSocket object at 0x0)> failed with error
```

pyinstaller command:

`python -m eel main.py web --console --onefile --icon=ico.ico`

**mp3 files don't play but wav files works...**

Comment: You could just go on a conversion website https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav and convert the MP3 file to WAV

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```
import pygame
mp3_file = 'song.mp3'
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3_file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    clock.tick(10)
```

This should play the music and run the rest of the game.

You are able to do the following as well:

```
import pygame
mp3_file = 'song.mp3'
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3_file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

But the game will stop executing and wait for the mp3 to finish. This is because of `pygame.event.wait()`

There are many examples here: [Play MP3 in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746263/how-can-i-play-an-mp3-with-pygame)