# Unable to load music

Tags: python, pygame

I tried a very simple code of playing music using pygame, however the cmd launches and then shuts down immediately without giving any substantial output. Please find the code attached below.

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("elvis.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: You probably need to do it within a game loop, not just by itself

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746263/how-can-i-play-an-mp3-with-pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the music to finish playing:

```py
from pygame import mixer
import time

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("elvis.mp3")
mixer.music.play()

while mixer.music.get_busy():
   time.sleep(0.01)

mixer.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `pygame` [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) it says:

> Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead.

So try to convert the file to another format, like WAV or OGG.

You could also use the absolute path to the file:
`full/path/to/your/file/elvis.mp3`

Also make sure that `elvis.mp3` is in your project folder.